# How do I retroactively change a default value for a column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

When I add a default constraint to a Column in SQL Server 2017 it sets the default for all future record entries.

```
ALTER TABLE Products  ADD CONSTRAINT DFC_PictureDefault DEFAULT [some_value] FOR PICTURE
```

When I did this the first time the column entries were null and it was easy for me to just write an UPDATE statement. But this is for a web application and I want to write a statement that will be able to DROP the current CONSTRAINT and ADD a new one. The UPDATE all of the records with the old DEFAULT value. I can figure out how to retrieve the old DEFAULT value for the WHERE clause of my UPDATE statement.
A practical use for this is if a client has an image of a company logo for all products that don't currently have a product image but decides to alter their brand and change their logo.

Comment: Why are you changing the default values regularly? And if the default changes why is the existing data needing to be updated? I would suggest you look in the current constraint to find the current default. That is where the default value is kept.

Comment: If you are going to do it on regular basis, consider changing your design and keep current default value in another table. If it is just one time update, you can get the old value from your database configuration.